# Parsing CSV into multidimensional array

Tags: php, csv

I have a CSV file whose contents are:

```
jobname1, address11, address12, address13, date
item11, chilled, 2kg
item12, chilled, 20kg
jobname2, address21, address22, address23, date
item21, chilled, 2kg
item22, chilled, 20kg
```

How do I parse this into a multi-dimensional array in PHP, where `item11` and `item12` are appended to the `jobname1` array? In the same way, I want `item21` and `item22` to be appended to the `jobname2` array. The output of `var_dump` should be something like this:

```
array[0] = jobname1
           address11
           address12
           address13
           date
           item[0] = item11
                     chilled
                     2kg
           item[1] = item12
                     chilled
                     20kg
array[1] = jobname2
           address21
           address22
           address23
           date
           item[0] = item21
                     chilled
                     2kg
           item[1] = item22
                     chilled
                     20kg
```

Comment: Could you add your code to the question?

Answer (score 0):

You would use something like this.

```
$fp = fopen("source.csv", "r");
$results  = array();
$curContext = null;

while ($rec = fgetcsv($fp)){
    switch (count($rec)){
         case 5:
             // header object
             if ($curContext){
                 $results[] = $curContext;
             }
             $curContext = $rec;
             $curContext["items"] = array();
             break;
         case 3:
             $curContext["items"][] = $rec;
             break;
    }
}
// push the last one onto the array
$results[] = $curContext;
```